# mysql data folder permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions

When I try to start the service MySQL55 I get an error saying:

> Could not start the MySQL55 service on local computer
>           Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

I ran Process Monitor which shows me an Access denied:

```
   C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL Server 5.5\data\JIMSDESKTOP.PID
```

This is the current permission settings that I have:

```
    FILEACL "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data" /S "JIMSDESKTOP\Administrator":RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "JIMSDESKTOP\ASPNET":RrRaRepWwAWaWe /S "JIMSDESKTOP\IUSR_JIMSDESKTOP":RrRaRepWwAWaWe /S "JIMSDESKTOP\Jim":RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /S "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE":RrRaRepWwAWaWe /S "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM":RrRaRepWwAWaWePXDDcO /REPLACE /PROTECT
```

What user is MySQL using to try to access JIMSDESKTOP.PID ?

How can I make sure MySQL has the proper authority?

In Process Monitor should I be filtering on something else besides mysqld.exe?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Process Monitor allowed me to add another column called User.  On the lines that say Access Denied it says the user is NT Authority\System.  I realize that is a special authority and I don't think I can add it to directory permissions.  I have added Network (Full control) and System (Full control).  As you can see I had the user Jim with Full control and ASPNET with Full control and Administrator with Full control. And IUSR_JIMSDESKTOP with full control.  I Restarted the PC.  The service still failed with the same error.  I ran a repair on MySQL and re-booted.  I received the same error in starting the MySQL55 service.  Just for fun I added Everyone to the permissions of the data folder and the service started.  I realize I shouldn't leave it with Everyone having permissions and I am still looking for an answer as to what I can do to fix the permissions.